# Are class generation functions allowed in ES6?

Tags: javascript

I need to create classes by some parameters. I want to do it with a function. I tried it using node.js v7.0 it looks working well but I'm wondering whether it's allowed by es6 specification.

For example:

```
const MyClassGenerator = (something) => {
  return class GeneratedClass {
    get type() {
      return something;
    }
  }
}

class MyInheritedClass extends MyClassGenerator('foo') {
  ...
}

new MyInheritedClass().type // => 'foo'
```

Comment: Isn't the new `class XXX` syntax just syntactic sugar? If so, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `class` syntax can be used both for declarations and as expressions, in any scope - it doesn't need to be (module-) top-level.

A function that returns classes is very well possible and does, as you experienced, work as expected. However, it often is a bad ida:

- the generated classes are usually quite similar to each other, yet they are lacking a common superclass
- if used in an `extends` clause, it often introduces an unnecessary level of inheritance.

To counter point 1, you can let all generated classes `extend` a shared one:

```
class Base {
  get type() {
    return this.constructor.type;
  }
}
const MyClassGenerator = (something) => {
  class GeneratedClass extends Base {}
  GeneratedClass.type = something;
  return GeneratedClass
}
```

<sub>(not too useful in this case, but often a good approach)</sub>

To counter point 2, you usually don't want to use `extends` for mixing generated stuff into your class. Rather use a decorator!

```
function myClassDecorator = (something, constructor) => {
  Object.defineProperty(constructor.prototype, "type", {
    get() {
      return something;
    },
    configurable: true
  });
  return constructor;
}

let MyInheritedClass = myClassDecorator('foo', class {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> JavaScript classes **introduced in ECMAScript 6** are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance.

and

> [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)
> The definition of 'Class definitions' in that specification.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions)

Comment: I don't see how that answers the question?